# Network Problems

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, hot-spot

**Hi People!** At first, I am a beginner, so I don't know many things. I'm having a problem with wireless network: **I can't connect to my wi-fi**, opening Network Manager in System Settings gives me this:

[image]

If you can open it, it shows me Wireless Hotspot, instead of Wi-Fi. What shall I do just to connect to my Wi-Fi and enjoy Ubuntu? *Maybe resetting will help?*
Thank you!

P.S. When I turn it off it shows my wi-fi, but doesn't connect to it. My computer params:

[image]

I have: ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64-bit OS. When I plug in Etherned Cable, I have internet.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` command:

> 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless
>   Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)  Subsystem: Lite-On
>   Communications Inc AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:6628]    Kernel
>   driver in use: ath9k  Kernel modules: ath9k

Comment: Switch off the Hotspot. The "On" icon on top right is a slider that you can slide to the left. Then the Wi-Fi will act as a normal network card.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: After you turn off 'Hot Spot' and click the Network Manager icon at the top, the little up-down arrows in your case, do you see wifi as an option? Do you see networks?

Comment: @chili555, After turning it off I see this:
https://pp.vk.me/c636823/v636823182/25a1f/TJoTeGxc-zU.jpg
There are networks, my is among them, but I can't connect to it ;(

Comment: Are ther any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep ath` Or else: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork | tail -n10` Please post the results here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555, 
Results:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23090335/ - `dmesg | grep ath`,  http://paste.ubuntu.com/23090349/ - `cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork | tail -n10`

Comment: @chili555, maybe do you have a way to communicate to you easier, because I have some details, which are too big for this topic

Comment: Please join me in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44498/discussion-with-space-and-chili555

Comment: @chili555, it seems I can't talk there, I must have 20 reps (

Comment: I'm not sure what else we can do. I notice some very interesting lines in your syslog about iptables. Is the firewall set to interfere? What is: `sudo ufw status`

Comment: Also, when you click the Network Manager icon and Edit Connections, what is the mode under Wifi? It should be Client. If it isn't change it and restart NM: `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: First Output: Status: inactive.  https://pp.vk.me/c636823/v636823182/25cd6/B9YGZL0hNWY.jpg - Edit Connections

Comment: Highlight *Wi-Fi* and select Edit. What is the mode? Client?

Comment: Yes, it is! It is client

Comment: Does: `iwconfig` show `Mode: Managed`? That is actually the same as client. What happens when you click on your network? Does it try and fail or what? Are you asked for the WPA2 password? Your paste actually look great! Let's also have a paste for: `dmesg | grep wlan0`

Comment: Let me get skype going. No video, I'm shy. I'm on skype: chili555

Comment: Output from `iwconfig` shows Mode: Managed. When I actually click my network (after I leave a default hot-spot window, it just reload the page. Once entered the password,  I was never more asked for it. The paste: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23090491. I'm shy too, but we can do kinda chat, I think, it is anyway easier to write letters in skype

Comment: Your paste looks great. Looks like you connected perfectly. I'm waiting on Skype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please turn off HotSpot mode. Be certain the the WiFi mode in Network Manager is set to Client. Next, Select IPv4 settings and select Automatic (DHCP). Finally, detach the ethernet cable or else disconnect the ethernet in Network Manager. Finally, restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I believe you will then connect. Test:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns, you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

Switch off the wireless hotspot. If that doesn't work then I would first post your computers specs including the version of Ubuntu you installed, then connect a wired ethernet cable and make sure you can get internet that way.

Then I would go and enable proprietary drivers in your settings: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/drivers

When you disable the hotspot and try to connect to your wifi, what does it say or do?

Comment: I added changes in my topic, look there, thank you for attention

Comment: More, there is no driver like that in this tutorial, I have only NVIDIA nad unknown

Comment: The only proprietary driver this installs is for Broadcom. He has an Atheros.

Comment: @chili555,  maybe there is a way by resetting my network manager ? I have already tried restarting, resetting, reinstalling network manager, but there is no different result.